# how to get total number of ArangoDB AQL for paging

Tags: arangodb, aql

AQL support basic AQL for paging by `LIMIT offset, count`. But I need to get the total number of the query in order to know the total pages. How to get the total count of the query?

I know the `LENGTH` function to get the count of some collection, but maybe it doesn't suit for the following:

```
FOR v in 2 any 'Collection/id1' GRAPH 'graph-name' FILTER ... LIMIT 10 RETURN distinct v.
```

I want to get the total number, but I can't get it by `RETURN distinct LENGTH(v)`

I now can implement this in a ungraceful way:

```
LET nodeList=(FOR v IN 2 any 'Collection/id1' GRAPH 'graph-name' FILTER ... RETURN distinct v)
FOR v IN 2 any 'Collection/id1' GRAPH 'graph-name' FILTER ... limit 10 RETURN distinct {'nodes': v, 'total':LENGTH(nodeList)}
```

Is there any other good idea to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer from the arangodb spring data project.

`AqlQueryOptions` has `fullCount()` function, to return the total count of the query.

and you can return the `PageImpl` which contains the query content and the pagination info.